# Sharing directory in network c#

Tags: c#, file, networking, network-programming, directory

I have to copy files from a distant directory in the same network. i succed to access to this directory :

```
   string[] parts = Regex.Split(@directory_path, @"\\");
               // l'emplacement de repertoire \\nom de la machine\nomde repertoire
             string distant_directory =  @"\\"+Environment.MachineName+ @"\" + parts[parts.Length - 2];
            string local_directory = @"StlDirectory";
            CopyDir(distant_directory, local_directory);
```

the function of copy is the following :

```
 public  void CopyDir(string sourceDir, string destDir)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir);
            if (dir.Exists)
            {
                string realDestDir;
                if (dir.Root.Name != dir.Name)
                {
                    realDestDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(destDir, dir.Name);
                    if (!Directory.Exists(realDestDir))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(realDestDir);
                }
                else realDestDir = destDir;
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
                    CopyDir(d, realDestDir);
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
                {

                    string fileNameDest = System.IO.Path.Combine(realDestDir, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
                    if (!File.Exists(fileNameDest))

                    File.Copy(file, fileNameDest, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

But an error appears `Could not find a part of the path 'StlDirectory \ BM529234-CRL39-LF.stl'` .

1. Why this error appears?
2. How can i fix it?

Comment: can you add your address?

Comment: I think there is a problem while spliting your address,this error appears `Could not find a part of the path 'StlDirectory \ BM529234-CRL39-LF.stl'` because Directory dosent exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ensured that what ever application IIS Application Pool etc has security permissions to access this directory?

Answer (score 0):

I thought that even the destination repertory is not exist the copy's function works (creation of repertory + copy) but it is not the case